# Sort elements in single-linked list in C

Tags: c, list

How can I sort elements in single-linked list (by some value like list->id)? The idea I've came up with is to find maximal value and save its index. Then iterate through the list so that the *head pointer points to that element...And then swap this element with the first one. The last sentence... how can I do that?

Comment: You would sort it the same as you would a list or any other data structure: there are various sorts available at various O(n) complexities. How you swap an element in a particular implementation of a linked list - depends on how you implement the linked list. Surely you could use the famous C "swap" function, if your field is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often easier to just swap the data, rather than "re-linking" the list so the order of the actual list nodes is altered.

If your field is an integer, you could do something like:

```
static void swap_ids(ListNode *a, ListNode *b)
{
  const int a_id = a->id;

  a->id = b->id;
  b->id = a_id;
}
```

Comment: Great thinking :) Still if the list contains more complex elements it is possible that swapping requires more operations than re-linking. +1 in this case, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best approach on how to sort a list is to implement [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Still what you try to do is known as selection sort and is doable(actually it is not very hard). You need to keep a **pointer** to the **smallest** element of the list and then move links so that it is placed before the head element(remember to move head too). I am saying you need to choose the minimum element as usually you only keep a pointer to head in a single linked list.